# Programming auto timed 3-image slideshow with loop

Tags: image, gallery, slideshow, fade, timed

I design websites using HTML/CSS and i just recently started using jQuery to add to my designs. i've been stripping code apart from different questions similar to mine but never helpful enough, im not just not experienced enough with the program. I'm basically looking for a way to have 3-images cycle by fading into each other over and over. That's it, it would go like this:

1)website loads/image 1 fadeIn
2)wait 5 seconds
3a)image 1 fadeOut 'fast'
   3b)image 2 fadeIn (this is to not show the background between images when they're fading)
4)repeat until last image fadeIn
5)smoothly loop back into image 1

I would totally appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Use [jquery cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) with fade effect: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/browser.html